# Can Mozilla Thunderbird Differentiate between New Messages and Replied to Messages?

Tags: filter, tags, thunderbird

Is there anyway in Thunderbird to differentiate between new messages and messages that have been sent to me as a reply to an earlier message?   The question might be equivalent of if there is a way that Thunderbird can send messages which have Re:  in the subject line to a specific folder since such messages for me have higher priority to reply to them.

Thanks,
Shannon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found the answer and it extremely simple.  Just select tools |Message Filters from the menu and create a filter that says any message with subject line starting with Re: to whatever folder that you might desire.

Comment: This will not work everywhere. In Germany, some mail clients add `AW:` instead of `Re:`.